# Finding the derivative of $|x|^2:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: derivatives

What is the derivative of $|x|^2:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The notation $| \cdot |$ denotes the standard norm of $\mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: Yes. Euclidean norm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 
$$|x|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$
Then we see that:

$$\frac{d}{dx_j}|x|^2 = \frac{d}{dx_j}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d(x_i^2)}{dx_j} =  \sum_{i=1}^n \cases{0 & $i \not = j$ \\
2x_j & $i = j$} = 2x_j  $$

Comment: I don't agree with the first line.

Comment: @Rebellos: Slow down. It is most likely just a typo.

Comment: My bad. It was a typo.